# How do I check if a remote directory exists in FTP server?

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I am trying to check if a remote directory exists in FTP server by specifying a path but my code failed to check when I provide a valid directory name. I want to check if the remote directory is valid and it is not a file. Here is my code:

```
public static boolean checkDirectoryExists(String file) throws      IOException {
        FTPFile[] files = myClient.listDirectories();
return Arrays.asList(files).contains(file);
}
```

Comment: Please visit the [help] and read about writing good questions.  What FTP client are you using? What is the value of the `file` argument to `checkDirectoryExists`?  What error message, exception or unexpected behavior do you see? How do you know the directory exists on the server? What debugging have you done so far?

Comment: Well u can see this was my first post. Basically I am sending a name to this method and wants to check if it is one of the directories( not files)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a loop to check each one yourself. Use `endsWith()` to check in the case of a relative directory path.

```
public static boolean checkDirectoryExists(String file) throws IOException {
    FTPFile[] files = myClient.listDirectories();
    for (FTPFile file : files) {
        if( file.getName().endsWith(file)) return true;
    }
    returns false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My trick is to use **listDirectories(directory)**.

- If directory exists but is empty : return an array of length = 0
- If directory doesn't exist : return an array of length = 0 too !!!

So I use **listDirectories(directory+"/..")**

- If directory exists : return an array with a least one element = directory
- If directory doesn't not exist : return an array of length = 0.

So just do :

- FTPFile[] tf = listDirectories(directory+"/..")
- exist = tf !=null && tf.length>0

Answer (score 0):

What you just Need to check is just ftpClient.cwd("your Directory Name")

this will return you integer values

`250` - If File Exists

OR

`550` - If File Doesn't Exist

For Example,

```
if(ftpClient.cwd(uploadDirectoryPath)==550){
     System.out.println("Directory Doesn't Exists");
}else if(ftpClient.cwd(uploadDirectoryPath)==250){
     System.out.println("Directory Exists");
}else{
     System.out.println("Unknown Status");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my method to check whether given path for which file exists represents a directory or a file. Here, there is no need to change the current working directory or to list all the subdirectories of parent directory and check individually for directory/file. Simply retrieve filestream from the given path, if inputstream is not null, then it is file otherwise it is directory. Here is the code.

```
public static boolean isFtpPathDirectory(String file_path)
    {
        boolean isDirectory = false;
        try {
            InputStream inputStream=ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(file_path);
            isDirectory=(inputStream == null);
            if(inputStream!=null)inputStream.close();
            return isDirectory;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return isDirectory;
        }
    }
```